# Curl of a projection of a vector field on a plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curl

I've been working on this question:

> Let $\mathbf F$ be a vector field on $\mathbb R^3$, and $\mathbf F_T$ be the projection of $\mathbf F$ on a tangent plane $T$ of a surface $S$. Show that the rotation of $\mathbf F_T$ equals $\nabla\times\mathbf F\cdot\mathbf n$, where $\mathbf n$ is a unit vector perpendicular with $T$.

I don't really get what this means nor how should I tackle it. I've done some tedious calculations, but I'm not sure if I'm making progress at all.

> \begin{align*}
> \nabla\times\mathbf F_T\cdot\mathbf k&=\nabla\times(\mathbf F-(\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf F)\mathbf n)\cdot\mathbf k \\
> &=\nabla\times\mathbf F\cdot\mathbf k-(\nabla(\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf F)\times\mathbf F)\cdot \mathbf k \\
> &=\nabla\times\mathbf F\cdot\mathbf k-((\mathbf n\cdot\nabla)\times\mathbf F+(\mathbf n\times(\nabla\times\mathbf F))\times\mathbf F)\cdot\mathbf k
> \end{align*}

**Edit**
$\mathbf k$ is the $z$-direction unit vector.

Comment: What's $\mathbf{k}$?

Comment: @PauloMourão The standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^3$, $\mathbf i,\mathbf j,\mathbf k$. I'll edit it.

Comment: Then I don't really get it. Take $T$ to be the $XZ$ plane for example. Then $\nabla\times F_T$ points in the $y$ direction and the left-hand side is always zero, regardless of the vector field, which is not true for the right-hand side. What am I missing?

Comment: @PauloMourão It seems that I've misinterpreted the problem. I've edited it exactly the same as my textbook says.. Could that help?

Comment: What does "rotation of $\mathbf{F}_T$" mean? It should be a scalar, since $\nabla\times \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}$ is a scalar. Is it $||\nabla\times\mathbf{F}_T||$? Because I believe that would be correct.

Comment: @PauloMourão Says nothing in the book, but yes, that would be correct.

Comment: @PauloMourão Can you please elaborate on why you would think that $\Vert \nabla\times\mathbf F_T\Vert=\nabla\times\mathbf F\cdot\mathbf n$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103744/discussion-between-paulo-mourao-and-wishofstar).